# Create grammar for retrieving vector of strings

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, text-parsing

I have a file containing data on the form:

```
fractal mand1 {
    ;lkkj;kj;
}

fractal mand2 {
    if (...) {
        blablah;
    }
}

fractal julia1 {
    a = ss;
}
```

I want to extract the name of data containers, so I want to retrieve a vector containing in the specific case `mand1`, `mand2`, `julia1`.

I've read the sample about [parsing a number list into a vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/num_list2.cpp), but I want to maintain the grammar in a separate file.

I've create a struct representing the grammar, and then I use it in order to parse the string containing data. I would expect an output like

```
mand1
mand2
julia1
```

Instead I obtain

```
mand1 {
        ;lkkj;kj;
    }

    fractal mand2 {
        if (...) {
            blablah;
        }
    }

    fractal julia1 {
        a = ss;
    }
```

My parser recognizes the first `fractal` term but then it parses the rest of the file as single string item instead that parse it as I want.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
using boost::spirit::ascii::space_type;
using boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse;
using boost::spirit::qi::lit;
using boost::spirit::qi::lexeme;
using boost::spirit::qi::skip;
using boost::spirit::ascii::char_;
using boost::spirit::ascii::no_case;
using boost::spirit::qi::rule;

typedef std::string::const_iterator sit;

template <typename Iterator>
struct FractalListParser : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> {
    FractalListParser() : FractalListParser::base_type(start)   {

        no_quoted_string %= *(lexeme[+(char_ - '"')]);
        start %= *(no_case[lit("fractal")] >> no_quoted_string >> '{' >> *(skip[*(char_)]) >> '}');
    }

    rule<Iterator, std::string(), space_type> no_quoted_string;
    rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>(), space_type> start;
};

int main() {

    const std::string fractalListFile(R"(
    fractal mand1 {
        ;lkkj;kj;
    }

    fractal mand2 {
        if (...) {
            blablah;
        }
    }

    fractal julia1 {
        a = ss;
    }
    )");

    std::cout << "Read Test:" << std::endl;
    FractalListParser<sit> parser;
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    bool r = phrase_parse(fractalListFile.begin(), fractalListFile.end(), parser, space, data);
    for (auto& i : data) std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use error handling, you'll find that the parse failed, and nothing got effectively parsed:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91d9bde793b8a07f)</kbd>**

Output:

```
Read Test:
Parse success:
----
mand1 {
    ;lkkj;kj;
}

fractal mand2 {
    if (...) {
        blablah;
    }
}

fractal julia1 {
    a = ss;
}

Remaining unparsed input: 'fractal mand1 {
    ;lkkj;kj;
}

fractal mand2 {
    if (...) {
        blablah;
    }
}

fractal julia1 {
    a = ss;
}
'
```

---

#### What was the problem?

1. You probably want to ignore the "body" (between `{}`). Therefore I    suppose you actually wanted to `omit` the attribute:

   ```
        >> '{' >> *(omit[*(char_)]) >> '}'
   ```

   rather than `skip(*char_)`.
2. The expression `*char_` is greedy, and will always match to the end of input... You probably wanted to limit the charset:

   - in the "name" `*~char_("\"{")` to avoid "eating" all of the body as well. To avoid matching spaces use `graph` (e.g. `+graph - '"'`). In case you want to parse "identifiers" be explicit e.g.

     ```
     alpha > *(alnum | char_('_'))
     ```
   - in the body `*~char_('}')` or `*(char_ - '}')` (the latter being less efficient).
3. The nesting of optional quantifiers is not productive:

   ```
   *(omit[*(char_)])
   ```

   Will just have very slow worst-case runtime (because `*char_` could be empty, and `*(omit[*(char_)])` could also be empty). Say what you mean instead:

   ```
   omit[*char_]
   ```
4. The simplest way to have a lexeme is to drop the skipper from the rule declaration (see also [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))

Program logic:

1. Since your sample contains nested blocks (`mand2` for example), you need to treat the blocks recursively in order to avoid calling the first `}` the end of the outer block:

   ```
   block = '{' >> -block % (+~char_("{}")) >> '}';
   ```

Loose hints:

1. use `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` to find out where parsing is rejected/matched. E.g. after refactoring the rules a bit:

   we got the output ([On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/438b5d8db2f790e3)):

   ```
   Read Test:
   <start>
   <try>fractal mand1 {\n    </try>
   <no_quoted_string>
       <try>mand1 {\n    ;lkkj;kj</try>
       <success> {\n    ;lkkj;kj;\n}\n\n</success>
       <attributes>[[m, a, n, d, 1]]</attributes>
   </no_quoted_string>
   <body>
       <try>{\n    ;lkkj;kj;\n}\n\nf</try>
       <fail/>
   </body>
   <success>fractal mand1 {\n    </success>
   <attributes>[[]]</attributes>
   </start>
   Parse success:
   Remaining unparsed input: 'fractal mand1 {
       ;lkkj;kj;
   }

   fractal mand2 {
       if (...) {
           blablah;
       }
   }

   fractal julia1 {
       a = ss;
   }
   '
   ```

   That output helped me spot that I actually forgot the `- '}'` part in the body rule... :)
2. No need for `%=` when there are no semantic actions involved in that rule definition ([docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html#spirit.qi.reference.nonterminal.rule.expression_semantics))
3. you probably want to make sure `fractal` is actually a separate word, so you don't match `fractalset multi { .... }`

---

### Demo Program

With these in place we can have a working demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecdc5cac8209add5)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Iterator>
struct FractalListParser : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>(), qi::space_type> {
    FractalListParser() : FractalListParser::base_type(start)   {
        using namespace qi;

        identifier = alpha > *(alnum | char_('_'));
        block      = '{' >> -block % +~char_("{}") >> '}';

        start      = *(
                        no_case["fractal"] >> identifier >> block
                   );

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(block)(identifier))
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>(), qi::space_type> start;
    // lexemes (just drop the skipper)
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> identifier;
    qi::rule<Iterator> block; // leaving out the attribute means implicit `omit[]`
};

int main() {

    using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    It f(std::cin >> std::noskipws), l;

    std::cout << "Read Test:" << std::endl;

    FractalListParser<It> parser;

    std::vector<std::string> data;
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, parser, qi::space, data);
    if (r) {
        std::cout << "Parse success:\n";
        for (auto& i : data)
            std::cout << "----\n" << i << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f != l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Read Test:
Parse success:
----
mand1
----
mand2
----
julia1
```

Comment: For fun and glory, added [an X3 version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c88f93c2a4010b7) and here's the recorded live stream: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/fixing-a-nested-blocks-grammar-in-qi-x3/

Comment: `in the "name" *~char_("\{") to avoid` there something wrong

Comment: @Orient that's not required afaik, what's your source?

Comment: *~char_("\"{) try to search this string on the page. I don't know why cite is pasted wrong.

Comment: @Orient Ah. You meant to highlight a typo :) Well, it needs to be `*~char_("\"{")` which is why I didn't get it :) Thanks